# Swift: Convert Normal String to YYYY-MM-DD type String?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to convert a simple string to DateFormatter string so that I can pass it to the parameter of `NSDateFormatter.dateFromString.`
I have a String

```
let a = "20160114"
```

I want to convert it into `"2016-01-14"`
How?

Comment: check my answer its working fine

Comment: @Json Bourbne, you should post your `time-zone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For only converting string to given format 
you can use **insert** sunction of swift

```
var a = "20160114"

a.insert("-", atIndex: a.startIndex.advancedBy(4))
a.insert("-", atIndex: a.startIndex.advancedBy(4+1+2))

print(a)
```

print : "2016-01-14"

Comment: jason Bourbne : using this way there may b chances in case number of digits changes your date can be nil or wrong , for your problem exact solution is shared by @Himanshu Moradiya.

Answer (score 5):

```
    let dateString = "20160114"
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"

    let dateObj = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    print("Dateobj: \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(dateObj!))")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let dateformattor = NSDateFormatter()
dateformattor.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
dateformattor.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
//  here just pass your string that you want to convert into date.
let dt = "20160114" 
let dt1 = dateformattor.dateFromString(dt as String)
dateformattor.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateformattor.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
print("Time :",dateformattor.stringFromDate(dt1!))
```

Output :

```
Time : 2016-01-14
```

Comment: @Rob when ever i send any string in my system for convert into date or time at that time it default set UTC time that i created so i give it in my code so my problem solve it

Comment: @Rob ok brother thank you for give me this information. :)

Comment: Yep, that's better. Frankly, I wouldn't bother setting the time zone at all (and I certainly wouldn't do it twice; lol), but this works great. Thanks for the quick correction!

Answer (score 0):

this might not be applicable in general when dealing with dates and times, but if you only need to insert dashes (format is guaranteed to be same), this is much simpler solution

```
var str = "20160112"
str.characters.insert("-", at: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 6))
str.characters.insert("-", at: str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
print(str) // outputs "2016-01-12"
```

Comment: What's the difference between calling `insert` on the character view of a string, vs calling it directly on the string?

Comment: to be honest, I don't know. I suspect it's the same thing and str.insert just calls self.characters.insert with same params, but that's really just a guess. It should be safe to omit characters for sake of increased readability

Answer (score 0):

```
    var str = "20160518"
    let strCpoy = str
    str.insert("-", at: strCpoy.index(strCpoy.startIndex, offsetBy: 4))
    str.insert("-", at: strCpoy.index(strCpoy.startIndex, offsetBy: 7))
    print(str)
```