# Wrong converting NSString to NSdate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Team,

When converting NSString to NSDate it give me wrong result.

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString * currentDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *currentDate = [formatter dateFromString:currentDateString];
```

**currentDateString value is "2017-01-01"
currentDate value is getting 2016-12-31 18:30:00 +0000**

It was surprise for me is any thing wrong with in converstion?

Comment: it returns UTC time so U have to convert it into your local time

Comment: you need to include TimeZone info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c

Comment: You have to set timeZoneWithName property for this......

Comment: What is the current time you expect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356459/swift-convert-normal-string-to-yyyy-mm-dd-type-string/41356513#41356513 refer this question

Comment: Yes its return UTC, I expected 2017-01-01 18:30:00 +0000

Comment: @kiran You need time as well or just date???

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you haven't added timezone for date formatter. Update your code with following one:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSString * currentDateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *currentDate = [formatter dateFromString:currentDateString];
```

Now values will be

currentDateString = "2016-12-30"

currentDate = 2016-12-30 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: Only do this if you want the date string to be interpreted as UTC time instead of local time.

Answer (score 1):

Call below method with the Timezone string in which you want the date & this method will return you date of that particular timezone.

```
-(NSString *)getCurrentDateForTimeZone:(NSString *)timeZone{
    NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timeZone]];// Your timezone
    NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
    return localDateString;
}
```

This method will return you current date of the timezone which you have passed.

**EDIT:** If you need time along with date then modify the dateFormatter to

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"]; // you can modify the format with the way you want
```